# pdfTeX warning with Beamer class

Tags: beamer

Compiling the following file

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
First frame
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Second frame
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I get this warning

```
pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{\\let\040}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
```

Why does this happen and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug report (off-topic by convention).


Answer (score 5):

This is caused by a [bug in `beamer` v3.28/v3.29](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/260). This bug is fixed in v3.30, which will be available *via* CTAN later today and through TeX Live and MiKTeX within a few days.